# How to convert a string year to a DATE

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6

STR_TO_DATE doesn't work like I expect.

| STR_TO_DATE('2007', '%Y') | STR_TO_DATE('2007', '%y') |
| --- | --- |
| 2006-11-30 | 2019-11-30 |

`10.6.7-MariaDB-1:10.6.7+maria~bullseye-log`

Comment: What date did you expect? It seems to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=b8cc3f68408341a2b3d278f2fd445f54

Comment: I expect '2007' to produce some date in 2007, either '2007-00-00' or '2007-01-01', not a date in the previous year. I wouldn't be surprised if there's some mode that's affecting the conversion, but I'm running all default settings as far as I can tell.

Comment: I looked at all [sql_modes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) related to dates in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=7b40946de3c534c7e7334a6e0de2bcd9). `sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` will return `null` but for all other modes `'2007-00-00'`. Really messed up timezone information maybe (UTC-744)?

Answer (score 0):

Use string operations instead:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('2007', '-01-01') + INTERVAL 360 DAY;
+---------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('2007', '-01-01') + INTERVAL 360 DAY |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 2007-12-27                                  |
+---------------------------------------------+
```